# Adding A Column to an Output

Tags: powershell

I a creating a shared mailbox report in PowerShell and am pulling the required information into a variable as below:

```
Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress $mailbox -StartDate $startdate -EndDate $enddate |select Received,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Subject
```

This presents me with the below when exported to csv:

```
Received,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Subject
03/05/2019 07:29:26,sender@blah.com,recipient@blah.com,FW:Important Blah
```

I would like to add an extra column that contains the Recived timestamp in a different format as below:

```
Received,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Subject,Date
03/05/2019 07:29:26,sender@blah.com,recipient@blah.com,FW:Important Blah,03 May 2019
```

I've severely run out of talent and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Received` is already a `DateTime` instance, so formatting it however you like is straight-forward with `ToString()` or using the `-f` format operator.

Add a calculated property as an extra argument to `select`:

```
... |select Received,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Subject,@{Name='Date';Expression={'{0:dd MMM yyyy}' -f $_.Received}}
```